# emacs - startup window size changed from default to maximum

Tags: emacs

I use below code to setup emacs using fullscreen:

```
(setq initial-frame-alist '( (fullscreen . maximized)))
(setq default-frame-alist '( (fullscreen . fullheight)))
```

I wish it startup with maximized window, the behavior is almost as expected but the window size firstly with default size, then I can see it changed to maximum size obviously.

How can emacs startup to fullscreen in one step?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `initial-frame-alist` (`C-h v initial-frame-alist`).  In particular, Emacs creates the first frame before reading `init.el`, so you need to specify these things somewhere other than `init.el`.  Two common ways are to give the `--maximized` command line option, or to set the X11 resource `Emacs.Fullscreen: maximized`; either of these are applied before `init.el` is read and evaluated.

It looks like you're on OS X, which I don't have, and it may be different there.

---

Update for Emacs 27:

You can set these things in `early-init.el`, which loads before the GUI starts.